# Iterate over columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have an Excel sheet which consists of multiple columns. In each column there are multiple rows - not always the same number of rows, but never more then from row 8 to row 208. I need all values from each column in a new column as one ordered list, beginning with column 3 (being C) till column 23 (being Z). I need this new column (being at position AB in the same sheet) with ALL values and without empty rows, as it is the source for a drop down list.

This is, what I have so far but it does not work:

```
Sub createDDICListe()
   Dim c
   Dim counter
   Dim cnt
   Dim Start
   Dim Ende
   Start = 8
   Ende = 208
   counter = 8
   cnt = Start

   Set Spalten = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y"]

   ActiveSheet.Range("AB7") = "DDIC-Liste:"
   For Each c In Spalten
       cnt = Start
       On Error Resume Next
       For cnt = Start To cnt <= Ende
          Dim Cell
          Cell = Cells(cnt, c)
          If IsError(Cell) Or Cell.Value = False Or Cell.Value = "" Then
             GoTo weiter
        Else
            Cells(counter, "AB").Value = Cell.Value
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
weiter:
    Next
End Sub
```

How to iterate over the columns and in this "for each loop" iterate over the rows and copy the cell-value in the new column row by row?

Comment: `copy the cell-value in the new row`... where will be this new row? in same sheet or different sheet?

Comment: The columns in question go from column c to column z. The entries of each column will go in a new column being AB in the same sheet.

Comment: Post your sample data and expected result.

Comment: In each of the columns c to z does the data appear in a single block or are there blank cells in the middle of the data which need to be eliminated?

Comment: You need to replace `For cnt = Start To cnt <= Ende` by `For cnt = Start To Ende` (though there are more elegant ways to iterate through the values in the columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should do the job very quickly:

```
Sub MacroMan()

Dim x, y
    x = [C8:Z208]
    Range("AB7").Value = "DDIC-Liste:"
    For Each y In x
        If Not y = vbNullString Then Range("AB" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = y
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. It's exactly what I needed and lean

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
Dim pasteCell As Range, origin As Range
Set pasteCell = [AB1] 'Destination
Dim firstRow as Long
firstRow = 1
For columnIndex = 3 To 26 Step 1 'Columns from C to Z
    Set origin = Range(Cells(firstRow , columnIndex), Cells(firstRow , columnIndex).End(xlDown))
    origin.Copy
    pasteCell.Insert xlShiftDown, origin
Next columnIndex
Set origin = Nothing
```

You can adapt the Destination cell and of course the first copied row of each column.